# Proof : If $S,T:V \rightarrow V$ (V is finite) and $KerS=\{0\}$ then $Im(TS)=Im(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I have this problem :

Proof  : If $S,T:V \rightarrow V$ (V is finite) and $KerS=\{0\}$ then $Im(TS)=Im(T)$

My solution :

- Let $v \in ImT$ exist $w \in V$ such that $T(w)=v$.

Since $KerS=\{0\}$ Its injective, then exist such $x \in V$ such that $S(x)=w$, Therefore $T(S(x))=T(w)=v \implies ImT \subseteq ImTS$.

- Let $v \in ImTS$ exist $ w \in V$ such that $TS(v)=T[S(v)]=w$

Let $u \in V$ such that $S(v)=u \implies T(u)=w$.

Therefore $ImT \subseteq ImTS$ and also $ImTS \subseteq ImT \implies$  ImTS=ImT.

I'm not sure with my solution does $u \in V$, implies that $T(u)=w$, Could anyone explain that part of the proof,I don't really understand that since $T$ and $S$ are different transformations

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $V$ is final? Finite dimensional?

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{Im}(TS) \subseteq \text{Im}(T)$ part is fine. There is no problem. But the other inclusion, there is a subtle point. *"Since $\text{Ker}(S)=\{0\}$, it's injective. Then exist such $x \in V$ such that $S(x) =w.$"* The last condition is for surjective maps, not for injective maps.

Here is a hint: Prove that $S$ is a surjective map also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you explain on $ImTS \subseteq ImT$ Why there is "$u \in V$ such $S(v)=u \implies T(u)=w$" I understand why there is such $u$ since $S$ is surjective, but why it possible to conclude that $T(u)=w$?

Comment: There was typo. Actually $\text{Im}(TS) \subseteq \text{Im}(T)$ is fine, not the other way round. Let $v \in \text{Im}(TS.)$ Then there exists $w \in V$ such that $(TS)(w)=v.$ Now $(TS)(w) = T(S(w)).$ So $v$ is the image of the element $S(w)$ under the map $T,$ i.e. $v \in \text{Im}(T).$ Here we don't need surjectivity of $S.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still quite don't understad Lets assume $S(w)=p$ It known that $T[S(w)]=T(p)=v$ But how can I conclude that $p \in ImT$? The only thing I could conclude from $S(w)=p$ is that $p \in ImS$

Comment: Why do you need to show that $p \in \text{Im} (T)$? To show that $\text{Im}(TS) \subseteq \text{Im}(T)$ you need to show that whenever $v \in \text{Im}(TS), v \in \text{Im}(T).$ That's what you did.

Comment: Sorry typo I meant $T(p) \in Im(T)$ Instand of $p$